# how to view events of a non primary calendar?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I am using google calendar api for python for viewing events of the calendar.The following code gives the list of all the non primary calendar urls.here is the cod:

```
client = gdata.calendar.client.CalendarClient(source='app_name-v3')
client.ClientLogin('xyz@gmail.com', 'password', client.source)
feed = client.GetOwnCalendarsFeed()
print feed.title.text

for i, a_calendar in enumerate(feed.entry):
   print '\t%s. %s' % (i, a_calendar.title.text,)
urls = list((e.title.text, e.content.src) for e in feed.entry)
print urls
```

The output gives the urls of all the non primary calendars.An event can be inserted to any of these urls using

```
 client.InsertEvent(event, url)
```

but how do i view the events for each url?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a deprecated version of the Calendar API. Please switch to v3 and then use https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert where you replace the calendar ID with the email address of the secondary calendar.